# Close the Mobile browser window using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have developed a mobile site using asp.net mvc3 and jQuery mobile. I want to handle the signout event by allowing the user to click the SignOut button.

Can anyone help me to close the mobile browser window on click of the SignOut button. I tried the folliwng code:

```
window.close();
```

Using the javascript embedded in the View, but it is working for the IE browsers only not for the Safari and FireFox.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 1):

That's the only way that you can close the browser using script, so if that doesn't work, it can't be done.

Most desktop browsers will ask the user to confirm if you try to close the window using script. Apparantely some mobile browsers allow it without confirmation, and some ignore it without asking the user.