# JQueryMobile - pagecontainerbeforeshow: remove previous page from history

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Using jquery and the callback **pagecontainerbeforeshow** I want to remove the previous page from the navigationhistory - that is if the user navigates from page1 to page2, and the user clicks on the backbutton I want to exit the "app".

I found the same question here but I dont know how to implement the answer in pagecontainerbeforeshow?

[Jquery mobile, remove previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099905/jquery-mobile-remove-previous-page)

```
 bindEvents: function() {

    $(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function(event,ui){

        var destinationPage = ui.toPage.prop("id");
        var sourcePage = ui.prevPage.prop("id");

        d.lg("destionationPage: " + destinationPage);
        d.lg("sourcePage: " + sourcePage);
        console.log("page to be shown =" + destinationPage);
        switch(destinationPage) {
            case 'restaurants':
                d.lg('redirected to list');

            break;
            case 'offers':

                d.lg('redirected to offers');

            break;

            }
        }); 
}
```

Comment: Hint: You will need `pagecontainerbeforechange` event.

Answer (score 0):

[Bohr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1335313/bohr) ended up using [an alternative to change the back button behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11082512/7295772).

If a `div` with `id=the_id_id_of_the_page` was present

1. on `pagecontainerbeforeshow` event, the `backbutton` would be associated to the `backButtonExit()` function
2. the `backButtonExit()` function would trigger the exit from the app

   ```
   navigator.app.exitApp()
   ```
3. on `pagehide` the `backButtonExit` function would be removed from the `button` and the behaviour would stop

   ```
   $("#the_div_id_of_the_page").on('pagecontainerbeforeshow',function(){
     document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonExit,false);
   })

   $("#the_id_id_of_the_page").on('pagecontainerhide',function(){
     document.removeEventListener("backbutton", backButtonExit,false);
   })

   function backButtonExit(){
      // Phonegap
      navigator.app.exitApp();
      // Normal Browser
      window.close()
   }
   ```

this is a much simpler solution then yours, but it can also be integrated in your `switch` statement if you need. Also if you are not using phonegap [consider reading this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9296903/7295772)

Comment: Hello there :) 1- This is not phonegap 2- the events in your answer are obsolete.

Comment: @Omar I updated the `events` as [`pagebeforeshow`](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/) and [`pagehide`](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagehide/) are no longer user in `jquery-mobile` 1.6. It may [not be possible to close the mobile browser without the user consent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9296903/7295772) outside of a WebView. Thanks :-)